# Getting value selected when using react-native-modal-dropdown

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am storing user text input into states like so

```
<TextInput
    placeholder = "Hello"
    onChangeText = {(text) => this.setState({greeting: text})}
/>
```

I want to do a similar thing using react-native-modal-dropdown.

```
<ModalDropdown
    style = {styles.enterSearch}
    options = {this.state.gasOptions}
    onSelect {(renderButtonText) => this.setState({gas: renderButtonText})}
/>
```

With this code I can select what option I want but I cannot find a way to get the value of the text option selected.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason you have to put String in front of the value for it to actually read it correctly. This took me a while to figure out so I hope it helps someone else out.

```
 <ModalDropdown
        style = {styles.enterSearch}
        options = {this.state.gasOptions}
        onSelect {(value) => this.setState({gas: (String(this.state.gasOptions[value]))})}
    />
```